# Why are statements in the form of questions, that do not have a question mark, still considered a question?

Tags: discussion

On several occasions I have left statements on the site "these have caused me to wonder" and then stated  my curiosity in the form of "why did such and such", or "why did God" and invariably others will consider them to be a question even though I end them with a period and not a question mark. On most occasions a comment is left saying that there are to many questions being ask, or even on some occasions the question has been put on hold with that being stated as the reason. I respectfully ask that site users please pay attention to grammar before either putting a question on hold or closing it. And if there is still some question please leave a comment to the person asking the question, did they really mean for the question to be interpreted in a certain fashion.

Comment: I appreciate that you're seeking help in asking better questions. Many visitors (not only to this site, but to many SE sites) just get frustrated and upset, and don't try to learn.  I look forward to reading your revised question (should you choose to ask it in a re-formulated manner), and future questions.

Comment: @Flimzy Is my rewrite OK?

Comment: It's much more clear what you're asking now, I think, but it still needs work.  I'll add comments on the question itself.

Comment: Cecil, do you have an account on EL&U (English Language and Usage)? Maybe, they can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to add to what wax eagle said.

Basically, if people are perceiving there are more questions in the body then you intended to ask, then you failed to communicate effectively. If a good chunk of people are having trouble seeing what your exact question is then it is your duty to clarify it. It is not your reader's duty to stick to the exact grammar you have used, or otherwise try to interpret what you mean.

That leads into the fact that many questions posted on the site are written with poor grammar. There are also "questions" that don't have a single question mark in them at all. Yet, they are all still on-topic and remain open. You see that the existence of a question mark has less bearing on the perception of a question than you think.

Now, the difference between those questions and your most recent question put on hold is that those questions are clear and concise enough to understand (despite any failings in grammar), but your's is not (despite the perfect use of grammar and question asking protocols).

To fix the current question that you are probably thinking of you need to cut its total content by more than 80%. The easiest thing to do would be to just refer to a few of the necessary verses instead of quoting more than ten of them. That will make the post less intimidating. Second, really formulate your thoughts and narrow your question down to one or two "sum up questions," which should be the last sentences in your post. If those questions are off-topic at face value then there is about a 95% chance that any amount of explanation before them will not suddenly make it on-topic.

Comment: Thank you both I will keep those facts in mind and try to make my questions more pointed and concise.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if you're seeing "you're asking too many questions" then the *initial* question is already so broad that if there is even a hint of additional querying the question is likely too broad.

The key thing that I've noticed is that folks show up here and ask questions as if they've never read a thing about Christianity, religion or are unaware that the millions (billions?) of folks who self identify as Christians vary widely in their beliefs and doctrines and opinions. They *expect* monolithic "this is what Christians believe" type answers.

Additional question word statements as a rhetorical device are a good way to draw readers into the line of reasoning you're intending. However, very often, at least here, they are used to expand the scope of a question outside of a reasonable area for a question on this site.

While it is good to pay attention to the grammar, it's *not* the fact that you've used multiple question words, it's more the *general sense of the question*.

Please always keep in mind that this site is not in the business of dispensing truth. Questions here are best directed from the perspective of trying to explain, prove or defend a specific doctrinal point. Questions should not seek universal interpretations of scripture. If you want to know what the text says try Biblical heremeneutics. If you want to know what specific groups believe about the text, we're your site.